# Can you use JavaScript for the backend of a website And use php to connect to sql database?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, backend, web-deployment

Im learning web development for my graduation project, and I have been wondering if I could use nodejs for backend while making the database with MySQL and connecting both with php, is it possible or am I just gonna have to use other languages for the backend of the website?

Comment: the whole point of node.js is it sits on the back end (server), and the code there is Javascript. You can also connect to MySQL from node.js directly, so in fact you would not actually need PHP at all if you didnt want to use it

Comment: Sounds like you should probably do some basic research on node.js before you go anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript as a programming language can be used in both the backend or the frontend. The exchange of information between the frontend and backend is done with HTTP requests so the JS in the frontend does not *directly* operate with the language in the backend.

The most popular way to run JavaScript applications in the backend is through NodeJS. It is a little complex to learn, but rewarding! If you already know PHP, I suggest sticking with only PHP in the backend for now, unless you have a lot of time to spend studying.

PHP and JavaScript are not inter-operable; you can't combine both together in the same application. You *can* connect to or use MySQL with either.

If you want to start with building a JavaScript backend, find a tutorial covering NodeJS and Express.

Comment: I haven’t settled down on a back end language yet I’m between php and JavaScript (nodejs) while php popularity is declining a lot of people recommend using it for more dynamic websites on the other hand JavaScript popularity is growing because it’s both back and front end language however for some reason most articles I read recommended php over JavaScript so I’m currently hesitant I don’t know which one to choose should I stick with traditional php or go with JavaScript? 

I wanna build a modern dynamic website and I’m looking for the best/fastest way to do it .

Comment: @75Dude Selecting your path where to start can be hard. If you just want to get something done fast and you already know some PHP, choose PHP (no framework). If you want the best options for the future, choose Node. I've done both professionally and now I teach JS (MERN stack) and I think JS is more in line with the future and teaches web fundamentals better. If you want any job and get paid as fast as possible, choose PHP and specifically Wordpress. Both are not bad options really :)

Comment: Not sure if my ping worked there because it was an edit, so pinging again :) @75Dude

Comment: Thank you for your helpful info man! you settled it for me.